# Add new rows with formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I whant to add rows automatically onEdit trigger.

I have this formula:

```
function addRow() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
    sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 10);
    range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 10, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

It works perfectly but i whant it to make automatically when i have 5 last rows in my spreadsheet. It is possible ?

Comment: What formula are you trying to copy? You can perhaps use [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) in google sheets to do automatically without any scripts

Comment: This formula add 10 rows and copy formulas from last row and populate them. A have menu to do that but i whant make it automatically when my spreadsheet have 5 last rows :D